# nodejs. close connection

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have nodejs application with mongodb(mongoose). like this:

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
 var express = require('express');
 mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/my_database');

 .....

 var DocumentSchema = new Schema({
     title  : String
    , body  : String
    , date  : Date
 });

 var Document = mongoose.model('Document', DocumentSchema);

 app.get('/documents', function(req, res) {
    // get all docs
    Document.find({}, function(err, docs) {

       docs = docs.map(function(d) {
           return {title: d.title, id: d._id};
        });

       res.render('documents/index.jade', {documents: docs});
    });
 });
```

so All users use single MongoDB connection. Should I close connection after each request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you should never close the connection and re-open it again, leave it open unless you want your process to consume more cpu / RAM that it should.